# Attempting to Install toilet for roughed in basement

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, basement

Homeowner here with some plumbing experience - the majority of the time I was working new builds though and I want to make sure I get this right.

Basement already has half bath roughed in:
Pipe is 3.5" ID, 4" OD. The top of the pipe is 1.25" below the leveled concrete and the plug is 1.5" below the top of the pipe.
I am trying to figure out how to install a toilet here - my current plan is:

- clean out the drain.
- knock out whatever this plug is. (looks like knock-out - no visible seam, maybe an inch below top of opening.
- get a coupling and short piece of 3" to get the toilet drain above ground level. Which I think would require me to knock out some of the concrete around the drain to get the coupling set.
- fill in the missing concrete.
- cut stub out to ground level.
- install flange.

[image]

Drain in question

Am I missing anything or going about this the wrong way at all?

Comment: Pipe is 3.5" ID, 4" OD. The top of the pipe is 1.25" below the leveled concrete and the plug is 1.5" below the top of the pipe. I will work on getting some cleaner pictures.

Comment: Thanks. Put that in your question post, please. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

The thing you measured is not "pipe", it's the dimensions of of 3" DWV coupler fitting.
That means a toilet flange with 3" spigot connector may well fit with no further alteration. You need to clean out the plug and make sure the coupler is actually glued on to something.

Comment: Looks like you were right! I knocked out the plug and it looks like a 3x4 elbow to end the run.

With that, do I just fill in with concrete around it to get that all level, after I stubbed out some 3"? From what I remeber, I don't think a toilet flange alone would be long enough to get a good seal there - I could be wrong though and that would make things even easier.